# GTM eCommerce tracking

Tags: google-tag-manager

I would like to start tracking e-commerce with Google Analytics, to do this I need to pass the values of my data layer into GA using GTM. I have read endless amounts of documentation on the subject and as far as I can tell it should work, however I am still having problems.

The online store we use is actually a third party system (quote engine) so we can't change what is passed to the dataLayer, everything we need is passed to the dataLayer but I can't figure out how to send this data using GTM to GA.

My data layer looks something like this on the checkout page of the site:

dataLayer = [{

```
'u12': '18000011', 'u10': '31903296', 'u11': '159328761', 'u3': 'XXLX', 'u7': '58.97'

}];
```

The custom HTML tag in GTM I'm using is firing in the correct place but not sending the information to GA, the tag looks like this:

```
<script>

ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
id: '{{u12}}',
revenue: '{{u7}}'
});

ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
sku: '{{u12}}',
name: '{{u3}}',
price: '{{u7}}', 
quantity: '1'
}); 

ga('ecommerce:send');
```

Unfortunately this is not working and my Google Analytics is empty in terms of e-commerce transactions, any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: GTM creates a tracker with a random name, whereas this tracks to the default tracker.  So you'd need to set a tracker name in advanced configuration (e.g. "'myTracker") and then used it in your e-commerce-tracking ga('myTracker.require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js'); - see here:https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference?hl=en. This is probably not your only problem, but it's a start.

Comment: Just trying to wrap my head around this so the correct code would be:

<script>
  
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', 'myTracker');

  ga('myTracker.require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    id: '{{u12}}',
    revenue: '{{u7}}'
  });

  ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    sku: '{{u12}}',
    name: '{{u3}}',
    price: '{{u7}}', 
    quantity: '1'
  }); 

 ga('myTracker.ecommerce:send');

</script>
 
obviously with my own tracking code?

Comment: Yeah me too. I am implementing enhanced ecommerce in Android and still confused with documentation google provided. Google is so bad at making tutorial...

Comment: I would really suggest that you do not use a custom HTML tag. Rather make a custom javascript variable that maps your custom datalayer to the  specification in Mindbreakers answer and pushes it to the GTM datalayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google pushes the enhanced ecommerce tracking thing. It is hard to find the old documentation of the standard ecommerce tracking.

[GA Ecommerce Tracking with Google Tag manager](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169?hl=en&rd=2)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was a combination of the two answers. I used Mindbreakers link as a template to create the custom data layer suggested by Eike Pierstorff and then used a standard transaction tag in GTM to send the information.

I would like to say a huge thanks to Eike Pierstorff and Mindbreaker for helping me with this.

[image: It's actually working!!!!!!!!!!!!!!]

Comment: No problem :). Feel free to contact me again.